# How to change python generator into Keras Sequence object?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, generator, sequence

I am working on a regression problem. My CNN trains on data which has shape **32x513x30** - **32 instances of 513x30** per batch, and then **4810** batches.

I have these batches saved in a directory, each named "batch#number.npy".

Whilst using a Python generator, I keep getting a warning from TensorFlow:

> WARNING:tensorflow:Using a generator with `use_multiprocessing=True`
>   and multiple workers may duplicate your data. Please consider using
>   the `keras.utils.Sequence` class.

I figured out how to load them using a Python generator. However, whilst using multiprocessing, it is advised to use Keras' Sequence class: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/Sequence

Unfortunately, that's where things get a bit too complicated for me.
Here's the code I've been using:

```
def batch_gen(num):

    os.chdir('mydirectory/train')

    for n in num:
        placeholder = np.load('batch#' + str(n) + '.npy')
        X = placeholder[:,:513,:]
        Y1= placeholder[:,513:,:]

        Y = X * Y1

        X = X / normalization # normalize X
        X = scale_mag*X.astype(np.float32)

        Y = Y / normalization 
        Y = scale_mag*Y.astype(np.float32)


        X = np.reshape(X,(32,513,30,1))
        Y = np.reshape(Y,(32,513,30,1))
        yield (X, Y)

my_gen = batch_gen(C)   # C is an array with indexes 1 to 4810 (looped by number of training epochs)
```

Is the way I am using the generator causing my data to duplicate during training? If so, how could I translate it into a Sequence class?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  class MyBatchGenerator(Sequence):
    def __init__(self, C):
        self.C = C

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.C)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):   

        n = self.C[idx]
        os.chdir('mydirectory/train')

        placeholder = np.load('batch#' + str(n) + '.npy')
        X = placeholder[:,:513,:]
        Y1= placeholder[:,513:,:]

        Y = X * Y1

        X = X / normalization # normalize X
        X = scale_mag*X.astype(np.float32)

        Y = Y / normalization 
        Y = scale_mag*Y.astype(np.float32)


        X = np.reshape(X,(32,513,30,1))
        Y = np.reshape(Y,(32,513,30,1))
        return (X, Y)
```